# Inspecting constructor parameters inside an autofac middleware

Tags: .net, dependency-injection, autofac, ioc-container

I have the following scenario:

```csharp
public interface IService
{
    string Name { get; }
}

public class A : IService
{
    public string Name => "A";
}

public class B : IService
{
    public string Name => "B";
}

public class C
{
    public C(IService first, IService second)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(first.Name);
        Console.WriteLine(second.Name);
    }

    public C(IService single)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(single.Name);
    }
}
```

I'm using **Autofac** as my DI container. What I'd like is to have Autofac resolve the dependencies of class `C` using the parameter name as a key in the case of multiple parameters of the same service type, **but only in that case** (the `single` parameter in the example should be resolved normally).

So the end goal is to have this behavior:

```csharp
var builder = new ContainerBuilder();

builder.RegisterType<A>().Keyed<IService>("first");
builder.RegisterType<B>().Keyed<IService>("second");
builder.RegisterType<C>().AsSelf();

// possibly modify the container behavior here

C test = builder.Build().Resolve<C>();

// output:
// A
// B
```

Hard coding the behavior in each registration (say using `RegistrationExtensions.WithParameter`) is not an option in my use case.
Using the [middleware feature](https://autofaccn.readthedocs.io/en/latest/advanced/pipelines.html#service-pipelines-vs-registration-pipelines) of Autofac I only managed to override the resolution behavior for **all** parameters (regardless of whether the parameter type is used more than once in the constructor).
This is what I have so far:

```csharp
public class ParameterNameAsKeyMiddleware : IResolveMiddleware
{
    public PipelinePhase Phase => PipelinePhase.ParameterSelection;

    public void Execute(ResolveRequestContext context, Action<ResolveRequestContext> next)
    {
        Parameter parameterKeyedByName = new ResolvedParameter(
            (p, i) => true,
            (p, i) =>
            {
                if (i.TryResolveKeyed(p.Name, p.ParameterType, out object instance))
                {
                    return instance;
                }
                return i.Resolve(p.ParameterType);
            }
        );
        var parameters = context.Parameters.Union(new[] { parameterKeyedByName });

        context.ChangeParameters(parameters);

        // Continue the resolve.
        next(context);
    }
}
```

and I'v added the following code right before building the container:

```csharp
// Add custom middleware to every registration.
builder.ComponentRegistryBuilder.Registered += (sender, args) =>
{
    args.ComponentRegistration.PipelineBuilding += (sender2, pipeline) =>
    {
        pipeline.Use(new ParameterNameAsKeyMiddleware());
    };
};
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

---

Update:
Thanks to [Alistair](https://stackoverflow.com/users/114400/alistair-evans) answer, here is a working solution:

```csharp
public class ParameterNameAsKeyMiddleware : IResolveMiddleware
{
    private static readonly ConcurrentDictionary<ConstructorInfo, IEnumerable<IGrouping<Type, ParameterInfo>>>
        duplicationCache = new ConcurrentDictionary<ConstructorInfo, IEnumerable<IGrouping<Type, ParameterInfo>>>();

    public PipelinePhase Phase => PipelinePhase.ParameterSelection;

    public void Execute(ResolveRequestContext context, Action<ResolveRequestContext> next)
    {
        Parameter parameterKeyedByName = new ResolvedParameter(
            DuplicatedServicePredicate,
            (pi, ctx) => ctx.ResolveKeyed(pi.Name, pi.ParameterType));
        var parameters = context.Parameters.Union(new[] { parameterKeyedByName });
        context.ChangeParameters(parameters);
        // Continue the resolve.
        next(context);

        #region Local functions, called only from the context of this method
        bool DuplicatedServicePredicate(ParameterInfo p, IComponentContext i)
        {
            var constructor = p.Member as ConstructorInfo;
            IEnumerable<IGrouping<Type, ParameterInfo>> duplications = GetDuplicateServices(constructor);
            bool isDuplicate = duplications.Any(g => g.Key == p.ParameterType);
            return isDuplicate;

            // gets groupings of multiple parameters implementing the same service (type).
            // if present, value is fetched from cache. otherwise value is reflected.
            IEnumerable<IGrouping<Type, ParameterInfo>> GetDuplicateServices(ConstructorInfo constructorInfo)
            {
                if (!duplicationCache.TryGetValue(
                        constructorInfo,
                        out IEnumerable<IGrouping<Type, ParameterInfo>> duplicateServices))
                {
                    duplicateServices = constructorInfo.GetParameters()
                        .GroupBy(pi => pi.ParameterType)
                        .Where(g => g.Count() > 1);

                    duplicationCache.AddOrUpdate(
                        constructorInfo, duplicateServices,
                        (x, y) => throw new InvalidOperationException("values should only be added"));
                }

                return duplicateServices;
            }
        }
        #endregion
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's a way to do this I believe by jumping up to the `MethodInfo` from the `ParameterInfo`.

You need to implement the conditional predicate where you currently just return true.

In that predicate, you should access the `Member` property on the provided `ParameterInfo`, `p`, which gets you to the constructor method (cast to `MethodInfo`). From there, you can access the parameter list and determine if there are multiple parameters of the same type. Return false if all the parameters have a unique type, that way the normal Autofac resolve can take place.

You probably want to think about caching the results of that check in a `ConcurrentDictionary` keyed on the constructor's `MemberInfo`, so you don't have to do that check every single time.